# Using JQuery Mobile inside Kendo Grid UI

Tags: jquery-mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Have anyone tried using these together? I am trying to inject JQuery mobile slide switch inside the Kendo Grid template control and it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: dataSource,
filterable: false,
sortable: true,
pageable: true,
selectable: true,
scrollable: false,
columns: [
{
field: "Firstname",
title: "First Name"                 
},                   
{
template: "<select data-role='slider'><option value='0' selected>Yes</option><option value='1'>No</option></select>", title: ""
}
]
});
```

I've tried looking it up at the jquery mobile's pagebeforecreate and pagecreate event and the select is still not existing at this point, I've made a workaround with the JQuery Mobile button by manually adding the css class, but looking at the raw html of the slide switch its more complex than hooking up a button.

Cheers!

Comment: i dont know about Kendo UI, you just need to find a way to tell jQM to enhance slider. `$("[data-role=slider]").slider();`

Comment: Got it! I've used kendo grid's 'dataBound' event to create the slider. Thanks you guys

`dataBound:function(){
$("table.k-selectable tbody tr td [data-role=slider]").slider()}`